# Postgres sql intersect with except relational division

Tags: django, postgresql, relational-division

I have a table called groups. I want to return the group number that only John and Mary are part of.

Think of a chat app, I want to see if these two existing people already have a group with ONLY them.

```
Group | user
1     | john
1     | mary
1     | dave
2     | john
2     | mary
```

How can I do this?

Here is the actual model

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    attendee = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Comment: Answer updated. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asnwer based on @arocks's approach, since @rocks's annotation is wrong.

```
Conversation.objects.annotate(user_count=Count('attendee')).filter(user_count=2, attendee__username="john").filter(attendee__username="mary")
```

That will return you a QuerySet of `Conversation` objects which have 2 members and members are *mary* and *john*

The reason you must you 2 separate `filter` is, your database management system need to create temporary subtables since you need to use same database column `username` twice for filtering. Your data

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me, I am using a single table with two keys -- nvarchar named guid the other is a foreign key of djangos built in User. convo_set = Conversation.objects.annotate(attendee_count=Count('attendee')).filter(attendee_count=2, attendee=self.user).filter(attendee=user2)

Comment: Can you share your models please, so I can write more accurate answer.

Comment: This still does not appear to be working correctly. will this currently work without the use of a many to many field? currently every time a user is added to a conversation a new row is created. when i search for members of a conversation i look for all rows that had a specific guid.

Comment: I am going to change my schema to use many to many and try your solution.

Comment: Your schema works when conversation is a many to many. Thank you for your help.